# Nested for loop for reading images

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, filesystems

I have written a code that opens a folder and compares the contained images to one another.  I am trying to get it to apply recursively to all the subdirectories within a folder.

I cannot use iglob's [recurse parameter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.glob) because it is not available in python 2.  I have to use python 2, because the code relies on opencv's SIFT algorithm, which is only [available](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/07/16/where-did-sift-and-surf-go-in-opencv-3/) for python 2.  I don't want to try a compile for python 3 because I have to hand the code off to someone else and they might not able to do the compile.

Here's the working code under iglob - proof that cv2 is reading the image properly is that image1 prints a list of points representing the image:

```
import cv2 #opencv 3.4.2.16 and opencv-contrib - https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/3.4.2.16/
import glob

for a in glob.iglob(r"/home/kate/Downloads/images/*"):
    for b in glob.iglob(r"/home/kate/Downloads/images/*"):

        image1 = cv2.imread(a)

        print image1

        image2 = cv2.imread(b)

        print image2
```

Here's my attempt to change it to `os.walk`:

```
path = "/home/kate/Downloads/images/"
for a in os.walk(path):
    for b in os.walk(path):
        image1 = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path,a))
        print image1

        image2 = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path,b))
        print image2
```

Error code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kate/hello/test3.py", line 31, in <module>
    image2 = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path,a))
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/posixpath.py", line 68, in join
    if b.startswith('/'):
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'startswith'
```

So I checked the `type` of "a" in both pieces of code, and in the working code, "a" is a string.  In the non-working code, it is tuple - specifically, it is a tuple comprised of three arrays: the root, the directories, and the files.  So, I changed it to this:

```
path = "/home/kate/Downloads/images"
for root, dirs, a in os.walk(path):
    for root, dirs, b in os.walk(path):

        print a
        print b
```

But now, "a" is an array comprised of file names.  Do I have to run another for-loop to get each filename on its own?

Comment: You can get SIFT in higher versions of OpenCV/Python. It is in the contributed library.

Comment: THANK YOU :-)  I will check this out

Comment: See the path at https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d5/d3c/classcv_1_1xfeatures2d_1_1SIFT.html. See the description at https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d2/dca/group__xfeatures2d__nonfree.html